# Is there a way to retrieve data from a second Elasticsearch instance in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an already an ELK stack. I wonder if it is possible to retrieve data from a second Elasticsearch instace in Kibana?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with *a second Elasticsearch **instance***? Another node or whole cluster?

Comment: This is whole different elasticsearch database, different than the existing ELK stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "second Elasticsearch instance", I assume you mean a second cluster. For this you can use Cross Cluster Search (CCS), which you will first need to [configure in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/modules-cross-cluster-search.html):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "remote": {
        "your_remote_cluster": {
          "seeds": [
            "<dns-name>:9300"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to add the Elasticsearch cluster in Kibana on which you configured the remote cluster (where you ran the `PUT _cluster/settings`). And finally add the right index pattern in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/management-cross-cluster-search.html) with `your_remote_cluster:<pattern>` (`your_remote_cluster` is the name you have configured in the PUT).

PS: If you are after a HA setup where one Kibana instance can talk to multiple Elasticsearch nodes in the same cluster, use the [`elasticsearch.hosts` setting added in 6.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.6/settings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Link to kibana configuration bellow. Kibana is only able to target one cluster, so you can target different url but with very important restriction.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

elasticsearch.hosts:
    Default: "http://localhost:9200" The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries. All nodes listed here must be on the same cluster.